# Janino ExpressionEvaluator not guessing all parameters?

Tags: java, dynamic, expression-evaluation, janino

Consider a simple use case for the `ExpressionEvaluator` class of the `Janino` library, i.e. when using it to guess the parameters of an expression, as follows:

```
public static String[] getParameters(String expression) { // Suppress exceptions
    try {
        return ExpressionEvaluator.guessParameterNames(
                new Scanner(null, new StringReader(expression)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return null;
}
```

While the above works very well (100%) for any type of expression I have used it with (including some very obscure ones), if any of the parameters starts with a capital letter, it is omitted.

For example, the expression

```
aVar + Another
```

will produce only 1 parameter (`aVar`) if passed to the above method, whereas the other parameter (`Another`) is ignored.

Is there any explanation for this behavior (e.g., are variables starting with a capital letter assumed to be class names)?

Most importantly, can the described behavior be bypassed anyhow (e.g., via some configuration option)?

---

### **UPDATE**

Apparently the limitation is more general and affects all parameters starting with a capital letter. This is a known Janino limitation (or feature), as explained in [JANINO-151](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JANINO-151) and mentioned in a [relevant discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/cascading-user/ZDAXd6BcXwg).

Indeed, the source code of the `guessParameterNames()` method of the [Janino ExpressionEvaluator class](http://svn.codehaus.org/janino/trunk/janino/src/org/codehaus/janino/ExpressionEvaluator.java) confirms this.